# My HTML CSS code doesn't work on Safari but works on all other Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created an animation card for my clients website, but the html css code doesn't work on safari (On Mobile) while it works on Chrome, Firefox properly. 
I have also added -webkit-animation: for browser compatibility. It works fine on andriod browsers but in iPhone safari animation doesn't work. Below is my css code. I am not able to understand what is the issue.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 wow fadeInLeft">
<div class="service-box icon-box iconbox-theme-colored bg-white p-30 mb-30 border-1px">       
    <a class="icon icon-dark border-left-theme-colored2-3px pull-left flip">
    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="icon-box-details" style="padding-top: 5px;font-family: 'VodafoneRg_0'">
    <p style="font-weight: 600;font-size:20px ">MIDC <br>Solutions</p>
     </div>
    &nbsp;
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Expertise in giving Maharashtra Industrial Development Corporation Solutions & Services in relation to it.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

   .icon-box {
        margin-bottom: 30px;}

        .service-box {
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top: 0;}

        .icon-box.iconbox-theme-colored .icon.icon-dark {
        background-color: #ffcb05;
        color: #383431;}

        .icon-box.iconbox-theme-colored .icon {
        color: #002E5B;}

        .icon-box .icon.icon-dark {
        background-color: #111111;
        color: #fff;}

        .icon-box .icon {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 70px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        -webkit-animation: all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-animation: all 0.3s ease;
        -o-animation: all 0.3s ease;
        width: 70px;
        text-align: center;}

        .border-left-theme-colored2-3px {
        border-left: 3px solid #005aaa !important;}

        .icon-box .icon i {
        line-height: 70px;}

        .icon-box i {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 40px;
        -webkit-animation: all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-animation: all 0.3s ease;
        -o-animation: all 0.3s ease;}

        .icon-box .icon-box-details {
        margin-left: 80px;
        font-family: 'VodafoneLt_0';
        font-size: 18px;}

        .service-box:after {
        background: #005aaa;}

        .service-box:after {
        content: "";
        height: 3px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: -3px;
        width: 0;
        -webkit-animation: all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-animation: all 0.3s ease;
        -o-animation: all 0.3s ease;
        -ms-animation: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;}

        .service-box:hover:after {
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-animation:800ms ease all;}
```

Comment: First of all, post your code, second of all, make sure that css you're using is compatible with safari or if you can use vendor prefixes

Comment: https://caniuse.com For checking compability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all prefixes for browser compatibility is given properly(provide code for more clarifications)

```
animation:
-webkit-animation:
-moz-animation:
-o-animation:
-ms-animation:
```

Comment: I just provided HTML & CSS Code for the same

Answer (score 0):

HTML should work across all browsers unless the browser does not support the latest version of HTML (which is HTML5).

CSS on the other hand may slightly vary between browsers. If you are using a animation you can use something like this:

```
animation: /* Chrome, Firefox */
-webkit-animation: /* Safari, Opera, Edge */
-moz-animation: /* Gecko (FireFox) */
```

I recommend using all of them incase some users use something other than Chrome.